# Javascript Leading Zero Function Argument

Tags: javascript

I am scratching my head over a problem that I am having with one of my JavaScript functions.

I have the following code:

```
 function getdetails(id) 
{
$('#details').load('load.php?id='+id);
}
```

The issue with this is, the id often starts with a leading zero or a series of leading zero's, which means they get cut off. I understand that it's treating it as an octet which is fine.

So I try to add the following

```
function getdetails(id) 
{
var id = parseInt(id,10);
$('#details').load('load.php?id='+id);
}
```

This however still cuts off the zero's. I have seen some of the padding functions that people have suggested, but for one I can not predict how many zero's there will and as far as I can tell, the zero's get removed as soon as it gets passed through as an argument.

Any suggestion on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Treat the id as a `string` instead of a `number` and it will never have leading zeros trimmed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine - it's the calling code that needs to be changed. Rather than calling your method with an integer parameter:

```
getdetails(0011);
```

Consumers should call the method with a string parameter:

```
getdetails('0011');
```

Comment: you solved my sily problem. I was totally looking the wrong place.